# My paragraph comes in one line instead of multiple lines as input by the user in a HTML text. I want my paragraph in the same format as input by user

Tags: html, paragraph, text-formatting

This is my html code:

```
<td>
<pre style="white-space: pre;" id="Comments" class="value">
text here
</pre>
</td>
```

I have used pre tag to take care of line breaks and spaces but it still displays each paragraph in a single line itself instead of multiple lines as was entered by the user.

Comment: <pre> should work... Could you post more of your code here?

Comment: <tr>
    <th>Comments:</th>
    <td><pre style="white-space: pre ;resize: none;" id="Comments" class="value"></pre></td>
 
   </tr>

Comment: If I paste this text, It shows just 2 lines in the output. One line for each paragraph.:                                                                                                               Crop DatIt was originally founded in 1929 as American Record Corporation and renamed as Columbia Recording Corporation in 1938, following its acquisition by the Columbia Broadcasting System.
In 1966, the company was reorganized to become CBS Records, and Sony Corporation bought the company in 1988, renaming it under its current name in 1991.